# Characterizing the unimodular functions from the closed disk $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ with constraints

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions, zeroes, algebraic-equations

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open disc. It is well known that if $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, continuous on the boundary, and is unimodular (say with a finite number of zeros) then $f$ is a finite Blaschke product up to some unimodular complex constant.
I am trying to understand the following set:
$$S=\Big\{f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}:f\,\text{is a finite Blaschke product and}\,f(0)=f\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big)\Big\}$$

It is clear that every finite Blaschke product that contains the factor $z\frac{z-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}z}$ is in the set, and each $f$ in the set has to have at least two zeros (otherwise it is one to one on the disk and cannot satisfy the last condition). However, given a fixed point $w_1\in\mathbb{D}$, can I always find a function $f\in S$ and a point in the disk $w_2$ such that $f$ vanishes only at $w_1,w_2$ (both are not $0$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$)? Moreover, is this $w_2$ unique in some sense?

This is obviously equivalent to finding $w_2$ such that $w_1w_2=(\frac{1-\sqrt{2}w_1}{\sqrt{2}-\overline{w_1}})(\frac{1-\sqrt{2}w_2}{\sqrt{2}-\overline{w_2}})$ (the RHS is plugging $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ into the Blaschke product corresponding to $w_1,w_2$ and LHS is plugging $0$ into it). I wasn't able to solve this equation algebraically, nor show such  $w_2$ exists. Any hint/help/reference would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Any such $f$ has the property that, for $g(z)=\frac{z-f(0)}{1-z\overline{f(0)}}$, we have that $g\circ f$ is unimodular and vanishes at $0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, hence is of the form you mention at the start. Conversely, given a unimodular map that vanishes at $0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we can post-compose with a disk automorphism to get a function of the type you describe. Is this helpful?

Comment: @BenJohnsrude: That settles it because if $B$ is the Blaschke product with zeros at $0,1/\sqrt{2}$, then $g\circ B$ is the Blaschke product with zeros at the two points $w$ with $B(w)=g^{-1}(0)$, so if $w_1$ is given, then we need a Mobius transformation $g$ with $g(w_1)=0$, and then the other zero of $g\circ B$ works as $w_2$. (Or were you being facetious at the end?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A description of your class $S$ can be obtained as follows.
Let $z_0=1/\sqrt{2}$. Let $H$ be the class
of all functions of the form
$$f(z)=ze^{it}\frac{z-z_0}{1-z_0z}\prod_{n=1}^N\frac{z-z_n}{1-\overline{z_n}z},$$
where $z_n$ are arbitrary points in the unit disk, and $N\geq 0$
is arbitrary. Now the general form of the function
of your class $S$ is $\phi\circ f,$ where $\phi$ is an automorphism of the unit disk and  $f\in H$.

Proof. For $f\in H$, evidently $\phi\circ f$ is a finite Blaschke product (times a constant of modulus $1$), and $$\phi\circ f(0)=\phi(0)=\phi\circ f(z_0).$$
In the opposite direction, let $g\in S$. Then there is $a$
in the unit disk such that $g(0)=g(z_0)=a$. Let $\phi$
be an automorphism of the disk which sends $0$ to $a$.
Then $\phi^{-1}\circ g=f$, and $g=\phi\circ f$, where $f\in H$.